# After Upgrade Windows Server 2019, My Website gives ERR_CONNECTION_ERROR

Tags: c#, .net, web, iis

I have upgraded operation system from Windows Server 2012 R2 to  Windows Server 2019.

When I requested the website, encountered an error named by ERR_CONNECTION_ERROR.

Why I got an error. I think, SSL certificates affected.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIru3.png)

Website is https://www.sekeryatirim.com.tr/

Comment: What's the error? https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://sekeryatirim.com.tr/ If a single machine experiences the error in the screenshot, that's likely to be a browser configuration, not anything wrong on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for the error ERR_CONNECTION_ERROR. It may be caused by the server side or the client side. You can try the following methods to solve your problem:

1.Run the Network troubleshooter. Go to Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Internet Connections.

2.Run the Windows Update troubleshooter. Go to Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Windows Update.

3.Reset Network. Go to Settings > Network & Internet > Status > Network reset.

If you still can't solve the problem, please post more information about the the error, you can check it in the console(use the f12) or event viewer.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to our websites as well after upgrading to server 2019.
After rebinding the ssl the issue got fixed.

1. Open IIS manager > right click the application for which https broke
2. Select binding
3. remove and add the https certificate again or simply use a different cert.

This should fix the issue.